# Old Linksys router is configured for SSL only but the certificate is not valid

Tags: google-chrome, router, ssl, certificate

I have an old Linksys E3000 router that is configured to allow only HTTPS connections to its administration, but the certificate simply doesn't work on Chrome, Edge, or Firefox.

I can view the certificate from Chrome, but it says "This certificate has an invalid digital signature." Furthermore, when using advanced and "proceed (unsafe)" it just comes right back to the same page.

I've tried Firefox as well, and it has the same impact. I can get it to the point where I doubly swear this is what I really want to do, but it still doesn't work. Edge doesn't even offer any way to bypass the error. I simply cannot tell them to just go ahead and bypass the errors.

I can probably do a hard reset if I need to, since I assume it allows HTTP by default, but of course, I'll lose all the settings if I do. The only other thing I am considering trying is using a virtual machine with some ancient browser that doesn't try so hard to enforce the new TLS best practices.

Of course, maybe the certificate is just totally broken for some other reason I'm not anticipating and it won't ever work. The certificate appears to have been generated today, possibly self-signed on the router itself. This is the certificate:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Is there any way I can access the router's interface without losing everything on it?

Comment: Have you tried internet explorer?

Comment: You will have to add the certificate to the certificate store for the user (Edge/Chrome) and Firefox certificate store.  The certificate is indeed self-signed and this process of manually trusting the certificate is perfectly normal

Comment: Downvotes for a well written, legitimate question. This place has lost its mind.

Comment: Tried adding the certificate as trusted -- didn't work. Tried installing an old Firefox version on VM -- didn't work. I think I bricked my router. Probably have to buy something new.

Comment: That cert has a 512-bit key -- I doubt you'll get any half-decent browser to accept it. It's also signed using md5, but that _shouldn't_ matter on a root/anchor. I remember haproxy (which uses openssl) used to default to not verifying cert on https backend (at all) -- if that's still true, you could set it up with a frontend (client-facing) cert&key meeting modern standards the browser(s) will accept, and the backend communicating with this antique. As long as you don't need to follow or post to or otherwise use any https: links that bypass the proxy. Sorry I don't have time to (re)test it.

Answer (score 2):

Use an apropriately old web browser.

Mozilla Firefox and SeaMonkey always use their internal SSL/TLS client library – not the operating system's TLS features – therefore using an older version will accordingly give you older SSL/TLS capabilities.

Old versions of these browsers are always available [on the Mozilla FTP server](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) (I'd pick the latest version of some-or-other ESR release, e.g. 38.8.0esr or 24.8.1esr). Installing them may conflict with the current version, however, so first try the [PortableApps edition](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Ed./) which can be directly extracted and launched standalone.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Something is bust with this certificate. Clearly a hardware issue with this Linksys that hasn't seen a firmware update in 5 years.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate is pretty poor - 512-bits RSA with a MD5 signature.

If you can't get any browesers to accept it, try running a reverse proxy in front of it and give that proxy a modern day standard certificate.  Install this certificate in your browser.

You may have to try various configuration options on the proxy to force it to not validate the router certificate.

Apache has `SSLProxyVerify`, while Nginx has `proxy_ssl_verify`, and Lighthttpd has `ssl.verifyclient.enforce` .